# I don't get the CheckboxFor html helper in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I don't why the `Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.IsChecked)` helper was implemented. Why does it force you to have to use a `bool` value?

From what I seen the regular html input can have a `"value"` of any `string`. So why does the html helper limit you?

I am having a problem right now where I would love to change the `"value"` to store my GUID but since it only takes in a `bool` I can't do this.

I see other people make a `HiddenFor()` to get around this but I just find this weird.

Comment: Here is an answer where someone created a own extension, it maybe is usefull for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195846/how-can-i-make-html-checkboxfor-work-on-a-string-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because usually a checkbox has 2 states: checked and unchecked. Which is perfectly modeled by a boolean. Now I understand your pain and agree with you that this could be a bit of a limitation because the underlying `<input>` HTML element allows for potentially any type. But this limitation is very easily workarounded by simply adding a boolean property to your view model and then bind the CheckBoxFor helper to this property.

Comment: To state it a slightly different way, the `CheckboxFor()` helper is binding a Boolean to the checkbox *state*, not *value*.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov -Well that is what I have right now I have a bool in my ViewModel for it. It just weird that I have to use HiddenFor() to hold the ID so I know that as well. Where it would have been nice it would all be in one control.

Comment: @chobo2, I agree with you, it could be convenient in some situations to be able to bind to another type than bool.