# Trouble populating edit checkbox or dropdown list with value from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

**Scenario**

I have a problem that utilizes a jquery repeater that way I can keep adding records in this case qualification records.

**Problem**

The problem I am experiencing is that I cannot get a Yes/No dropdown or checkbox to work or display the value that it reads from the database. As you can see,from the screenshot I can't select the value "no" to be displayed in my dropdown list, if true was selected, I wouldnt be able to get my checkbox to be "ticked"

The commented area of code shows some of the methods I've used, As you can see, I cant exactly bind act (Correct me here if im wrong) because it's part of another class so I cant say "Model.historyLead" or Model.act.historyLead.
I am returning all the other values but it's just the checkbox or dropdown list is not working for me.
I would greatly appreciate any help in solving this.
Regards

[image]

Part of my edit view

```
      @foreach (var item in Model.act)
 {
    <div data-repeater-item class="mt-repeater-item">
        <div class="mt-repeater-input">
                <label>Institution</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="hisotryInput" value="@item.hisotryInput" />
        </div>

               <div class="mt-repeater-input">
                    <label>Description</label>                                             
                            <div class="col-md-10">                                                           
                                @Html.TextArea("hisotrydescrip",item.hisotrydescrip, new { @class = "form-control", cols = 50, @rows = 5,@style="width:290px" })                                                             
                            </div>
                </div>

                <div class="mt-repeater-input">
                    <label>Lead Consultant?</label>
                        @*@Html.DropDownList("historyLead", null, String.Empty, new { @class = "form-control ", @Value = @item.historyLead })*@
                        @*@Html.CheckBox("historyLead", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",@value=@item.historyLead } })*@
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" name="historyLead" value=@item.historyLead />
                                @*<select name="historyLead" >
                                    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
                                    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
                                    <option value="vw">VW</option>
                                    <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
                                </select>*@
                    </div>
```

And model used

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CARICAD_App.Models
{
    public class repeatViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "textinput")]
        public string textinput { get; set; }





    }

    public class CON_consultantInfoVM
    {

        [DisplayName("Age Range")]
        public Nullable<int> ageRange { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Image")]
        public string image { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Consultant ID")]
        public string consultID { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required]
        public string firstName { get; set; }

...
        public REF_country REF_country { get; set; }
        public REF_nationality REF_nationality { get; set; }

        public List<actVm> act { get; set; }
    }

    public class actVm
    {
        public Nullable<int> id { get; set; }
        public string consultID { get; set; }
        public string textinput { get; set; }
        public string untypedinput { get; set; }

        public string dateinput { get; set; }
        public string textareainput { get; set; }
        public string radioinput { get; set; }

        public string selectinput { get; set; }
        public string activities { get; set; }
        public string hisotryInput { get; set; }
        public string historydateinput { get; set; }
        public string hisotrydescrip { get; set; }
        public string historydateinputTo { get; set; }
        public string historyLead { get; set; }
        public bool historyCo { get; set; }
        public List<string> multipleselectinput { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Include you code in the question, not images of it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Added it but was mostly to show my model loop

Comment: Your checkbox makes no sense. If the initial value of `historyLead` is `"No"` then it generates `value="No"` so if its checked it will post back `"No"`, and if its not checked it wont post back anything. Ditto is the initial value is `"Yes"` it will post back `"Yes"` if checked and nothing if unchecked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a checked attribute when your condition is true:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="historyLead" value="@item.historyLead" @(item.historyLead== "Yes" ? "checked='checked'" : "") class="form-control" />
```

You could also add a boolean property to your viewmodel and then use `CheckBoxFor` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195846/how-can-i-make-html-checkboxfor-work-on-a-string-field)

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstand how checkbox works.

1. `Value` of checkbox is sent to server when it is checked
2. If checkbox is not checked no `Value` is sent to server

With this two rules you can say that `Value` should be `Yes` so it will post back the value of `Yes` to server if checked. If unchecked you can add some logic `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(historyLead)) historyLead = "No"`.

But i would suggest changing property `historyLead` to `Boolean` and setting value of checkbox to `True`. Because of default value it would become `False` in case if it was unchecked.